# Simple and intuitive understanding of Java program execution

Tags: java

I started learning Java a few days ago and have been reading and watching some beginner tutorials, but I have a problem with the intuition of how the program operates and how I should build my program. Mainly, is there a simple and short description to describe a general frame how a program runs and what should be taken into account when building one? More specifically, the main activity of the program (see example). Is there a simple answer or kind of a 'meta code' example to get intuitive understanding as a starting point for learning?

For example, in procedural programming (e.g. C) simplified description could be:

The program always starts from `main()`-function in the source file, where there is usually a `while()`-loop, which gets repeated infinitely unless told otherwise. Other functions (different operations) can be called from the `main()` or from other functions. Functions exist **outside** of the `main()`, sometimes in different (importable) files. Functions are **always** executed once per call and the program returns to the point of function call after execution and **always** ends up returning back to the main(), to the initial positions where the first function of the chain was called. The program continues this behavior as long as the `while()` in `main()` gets repeated. After this, the program stops running.

I know it is challenging and I did bad job in the example, but it still covers the two essentials for an absolute beginner for a common way to write C program: How the program runs in the `main()` loop and how the program moves between functions.

I somewhat understand that in Java there are classes, objects created in the class constructor and methods within the classes, class extends and etc. But the proper order of execution is unclear. Can someone describe how this works in a similar fashion as the C-example. Do I understand right that the program starts always in the public class in the `main()`-method? How do you proceed from here? Is it okay to make e.g. a while()-loop there where you create and modify objects and run methods? In procedural programming, you can do basically anything with this same 'protocol'. Is this true in Java (or other OOP)?

Comment: Your description of C flow is very arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I know it is, but to write non-arbitrary example would require from me much much more than a small paragraph. But based on this arbitrary flow, one can create many arbitrary examples such as a simple calculator or a multi axis CNC-control system. So I think it could be ok starting point for beginner. Do you have a general or arbitrary suggestion for Java flow?

Comment: Is there a more specific question you'd like to ask? Maybe you are more focused on how a GUI application works in Java wrt an event loop etc.?

Comment: Sure, that would be one good example, pushbutton -> print or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to describe/define Java is that it is a Turing-complete programming language (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). As opposed to languages such as SQL, which is not Turing-complete.

Java (and before that OOP) was primarily created to address some of the trickier things to get right in C and C++ (i.e. memory & pointer management and virtualization of the executable (i.e. run the same Java program on all OSes)) but at its heart, Java can be thought of as just a next gen programming language in the vein of C and C++